# htaccess rewrite condition not working in internet explorer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, internet-explorer

We have mutiple websites with the same code. The problem is this is working correctly in Firefox, Chrome etc, but it is not working in IE.

My suggestion is that internet explorer sends a different/incorrect HTTP_HOST. But i can't figure out why. Can anybody help me in the right direction. 
I have posted the htaccess file below

what the code should do:
 1. Check if the request is for the sitemap
 2. redirect www to http
 3. if the website is not website.nl use http
 4. if the website is website.nl use https
 5. Use for all request the request.php file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml/?$ generate_sitemap.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^(www\.)?website.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((.|/)*)$ /request.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that Internet Explorer sends another `host` header than Chrome and Firefox. Probably what you're seeing is that Internet Explorer has an old and wrong rewrite rule cached (you're using `301` permanent redirects, they get cached in the browser). It could also be that Chrome and Firefox have an old rule cached.

Clear your browser cache or use private/incognito mode and then try again.

I can recommend using `302` temporary redirects until you have verified that all rules are working properly.

If the above does help you solve your issue:

You can test your rewrite rules here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be

You can view the request headers, including the `Host` header, in Internet Explorer's developer console by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> / networking view.

Also check Internet Explorer's and modem/router settings to verify that you're not accidentally using a proxy.

Comment: I found out it get's in an infinite loop. Only in internet explorer. It keeps connecting to https://website.nl. so i keeps excecuting the role https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: Found the solution: had to change HTTPS != on to RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
Thank you verry much