# ReWriteCond in .htaccess not working in IE11

Tags: mod-rewrite, internet-explorer-11

The purpose of this code is to prevent people from accessing a pdf file unless they are accessing the file from another page in https://www.example.com. If they are trying to access the PDF from another site, they are to be redirected to our commercial website https://example2.com. (It is to prevent people who don't have authorized access from downloading a PDF or from copying the URL for the PDF and sharing it with others.)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example2.com/ [L,R=301]
```

The code above worked fine with all browsers until a recent update to IE11 and now it ignores the rewrite condition and always redirects to https://example2.com even if you are linking from https://www.example.com. However it works as it should in Chrome and Edge.

I tried changing the rewrite to what I have below as I am fine hardcoding the URL, but got the same results:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.example.com/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

How do I get this needed functionality to work in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe IE has an old and wrong rewrite rule cached. You could clear cache in IE and try again.

Besides, you could test your rewrite rules in [this site](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be). I test with your first code and it says:

> This test string is not supported: %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER}

I test with your second code and it works. So I think you could clear IE cache and try again with the second code.

For more information, you could refer to [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532731/htaccess-rewrite-condition-not-working-in-internet-explorer).

Comment: Thanks for these thoughts, but I had tried all suggestions prior to posted this and had tested the rewrite rules also which is why I switched to the hardcoded rewrite rule.  Caches is not the problem as it is cleared and I have also tested using in-private browsing and it is still not behaving properly with either the dynamic or hardcoded URL.

Comment: Which version of IE 11 and OS are you using? You could check the network settings of IE to make sure you're not accidentally using a proxy. As the htaccess file works well before in IE, it maybe some settings have changed in IE after updating which leads to the issue. You could also try to reset IE to see if it works.